# Filter out other users comments. Visualize only own comments and editor role users' comments

Tags: functions, filters, users, comments

I have a similar request as per [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121354/use-comments-as-notes-visible-for-comment-author-only) but I am totally not into php and would not know where to start to make such edits based on the answer provided.

Would be great if anyone could help here. This is for a simple school project where teachers can share assignments with thier students. Students should not be able to see other student's comments to an assignment.

Is there anyone who could help with the task? The functions.php can be found at [link](https://gist.github.com/cbeltr2020/906f76b249a575f8578de2b67690a6ce)

Thansk in advance